# Block TV out for my application

Tags: java, android, video

I am developing an application that can stream videos. As per requirement it should not display the application content or the video playback happening on the device through a HDMI TV out or any such similar cables. Is there a way by which I can block my application from doing this?

I was not able to find much information regarding this. As far as I checked it seems there are a few devices which can do this.

See also Stack Overflow question *[Redirecting/duplicating the UI to an external output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868998)*.

Comment: Why would you do this to your users???? Why?

Comment: Also... what if the Android device, itself, is the TV?

Comment: It is as per the customer requirement. They do not want their content to be taken out in any form the device. If a video is streamed on a Tv there is every possibility that the user can record and distribute it.

Comment: I did not get you second comment. are you talking about Google TV running Android?

Comment: @Rahul, it is a ridiculous requirement, and you should tell them so. It is really just sticking it to the users. Recording video is a hassle. As long as TV is priced in a reasonable way so that legally buying it is more convenient and accessible than recording it, it's not going to be a problem.

Comment: @Rahul, yes, that was what I was referring to with my second comment.

Comment: The application that we are developing would stream licensed and protected content(like movies). If a cable can stream a video from a device to a TV don't you think it may affect its privacy? Moreover i only want my application to have this behavior. Is there any property in android that can do this?. Regarding Google TV can a application published on Android Market be accessed through Google TV as of now?

Comment: What does privacy have to do with the discussion (privacy is something people have, not TV shows)? No, it is not currently possible to install apps on Google TV.

Comment: I'm sorry it should be 'Piracy' . I found some intents that can be fired when a device is inserted into a Car dock but found none for my case. Any how thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way by which i can block my application from doing this?

No.

Comment: false answer commonsWare...check out NFL app...they do this...how they do it?

Comment: http://www.droidforums.net/forum/galaxy-nexus-general-discussions/193134-nfl-app-blocking-hdmi-video-output.html

Comment: @Dany's: "how they do it?" -- get a job with the NFL and ask them. There is nothing in the Android SDK that allows apps to control whether or not their output is included in HDMI signals.

Comment: @CommonsWare i just found out a way here: http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/05/29/how-to-use-the-hidden-hdmi-api-tutorial/

Comment: @Dany's: `HDMI_PLUGGED` is not part of the Android SDK at this time.

Comment: Please use the hidden Android intent “android.intent.action.HDMI_PLUGGED” instead. This is supported on smartphones running Ice Cream Sandwich and Jellybean

Comment: Is this answer still valid?